# html how to send data via post by clicking a string

Tags: html

One way to send data via post by clicking a string as below

```
<form action="the page I want to send to.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="data" value="the data I want to send">
<input type="submit" value="the string I want to show">
</form>
```

But, it will look like as a button.
And I don't want that. I want the string looking like as a normal string but it can send data via post by clicking the string.

Do you know how to do so?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643805/send-post-data-along-when-link-is-clicked-without-using-forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps by removing all the style of your submit button:

```css
input[type=submit] {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  pointer: default;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<form action="the page I want to send to.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="data" value="the data I want to send">
In this text is <input type="submit" value="the string I want to show">
</form>
```

This makes your submit button look like regular text.

Comment: Although it is almost the thing that I want, "the string I want to show" cannot perform inline. Do you have any solutions to adjust it?

Comment: Yes it is CSS. I just edited it to make it inline. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Does it apply to all submit inputs? How can I apply to only this submit input?

Comment: It will only be applied to submit buttons, because of `input[type=submit]`

Comment: But, I just want to apply to this submit button, not every submit button. How can I do?

Comment: add `id="form_name"` to the form, and change it to `#form_name input[type=submit]`

Comment: Is input[name=data] OK?

Comment: Only if the `name` of the input is `data`. But I think you are confused here. You can read more about selectors at http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: Only if the name of the input is data.
-> I just need to apply to this submit button only.

Comment: It cannot inline. Why?